# What's a title for a founder no longer with a company?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

I've seen it quite often that people refer to someone as a "former founder" or "former co-founder," but that's not really possible since a founder is always a founder. Once you found something, even if you leave the project that you founded, you are still a founder. You can't be a person who was at one time the founder of a project, but is no longer the founder. What's the proper way to refer to this phenomenon?

Comment: Estranged or divorced, perhaps? :)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/456046/14666

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest **founder emeritus**.

The [Compact Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emeritus?view=uk) defines *emeritus* as an adjective meaning:

*(of the former holder of an office, especially a university professor) having retired but allowed to retain their title as an honour*

Comment: Ooooh, this is a good one. I was originally thinking something along the lines of coleopterist's answer, but "founder" doesn't necessarily have to do with a business, so the person might not necessarily be a CEO. This one works for any situation, however.

Comment: Excellent! Going by Google, it also appears to be used quite often :)

Comment: @coleopterist - from our heightened towers, is that good or bad?

Comment: @bib hehe :) My guess is that one of "us" is a sell-out :P

Comment: @coleopterist - Now you're bugging me. We oligarchs got to stick together.

Comment: I think emeritus suffers from the same problem as "former founder", in that it implies you no longer *really* qualify for the title but are allowed to keep it anyway; a company's founder always qualifies as its founder on his/her own merits.

Comment: Both *president emeritus* and *professor emeritus* are used extensively, and indicate that the holder *was* a former active member in that position but now is inactive. The Latin root of emeritus means "earn by service".

Answer (score 6):

From what I have seen, this is either handled with "*Founder (no longer with the company)*", or something like "*Founder and former CEO of ...*". I do not recall seeing any single-word alternatives to these.

Nice question :)

Comment: This one works, but it really only applies to companies. If someone founds a club at a school then quits, they wouldn't be the "former CEO." This is definitely still applicable to companies, though.

Comment: @NickAnderegg CEO was just an example. It could be whichever title the founder held in the institution--former principal, former headmaster etc. But, I like "_Founder Emeritus_", albeit with the caveat that it sounds too ... prestigious and might not be suitable for all situations.

Comment: That's true. But in other situations it doesn't necessarily convey that a person isn't with an organization anymore. I was thinking about something like a college club. Someone could found a club and be the president, but if the next year they decide they don't want the position anymore, although they would be "Founder and former President of..." it wouldn't convey if they were still *in* the club. They could be the former president, but still be a member.

Comment: Founder emeritus does sound very prestigious.

Comment: If we are looking to denigrate the lackey, perhaps *instigator emeritus*?

Comment: @NickAnderegg In that scenario, just "_Founder_" might suffice, or "_Founder and senior member_" perhaps ... IMO, the fact that the person is the founder trumps his presidency.

Answer (score 3):

The title for a founder who ceases to work at the company is:

#### Founder

Founding the company is a specific, immutable act that cannot be "undone" after the person leaves the company.

The "past relationship" should be indicated in some other way, such as "Founder and former CEO" or "Co-Founder, who left the company in 1977".

"Founder Emeritus" as suggested in the other answer is *ok* for a condensed title, although in my opinion it suggests that an **official title** of "founder emeritus" was *awarded* to the founder by the company. I do not think that term would be appropriate for use without such an official grant by the company. That's also a title, unlike "founder", that *could* be revoked.